# Uninstall php5 installed from source

Tags: php5, uninstall

I have tried to install php5 from source , and it worked...

Then for some reason need to install the official packets, so i tried a make uninstall and for my surprise there is such make uninstall... so i tried delete all the installed files by hand.

Then installed the official debian packages and it worked fine... till i need install sqlite module, which give me the following error:

```
php --version
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626/sqlite.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626/sqlite.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.3.1-5 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Feb 22 2010 22:46:05) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

So i remember that manual install i did, and i think there is some old lib installed causing that problem, the bad thing is that there is not such make uninstall on the source code of php5...

```
php-5.2.13 > make uninstall
make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.
```

I have tried reinstall and purge all php related packages via aptitude with not success.

OS: Debian Squeeze.

> uname -a Linux desktop
>   2.6.32-trunk-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Jan 10 22:40:40 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

debsums might help find stuff that was clandestinely overwritten by the source install...

Answer (score 0):

It is the `extention_dir` setting in php.ini do `ls /usr/lib/php5/` to find the correct value.